# Regex to check special characters in the filename in an input directory/path

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a FileUpload control and need to validate the FileName browsed using a RegularExpressionValidator. I'm using this regex: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*$`. But it is also detecting the special characters in the directory. E.G. the `\` or `:` in the `C:\Sample FIle.txt`. The other catch is it is required to use a static class to store the regex expression. So on load of the user control that contains the FileUpload control, there is something like, `this.RegexValidatorControl.ValidationExpression = SampleClass.FileNameRegex`, where FileNameRegex is declared as static string `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*$`.

Any help on how I should approach this?

There are 2 requirements:

1. RegularExpressionValidator should be used.
2. The regex is stored in a static member of a static class.

Comment: FYI `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*$` will never ever match a backslash or `:` so I suspect the problem isn't your regex. Also note that your regex will match empty strings, so you may use `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]+$`. If you have a [non-unicode implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx#regexnet_topic8), you might as well use `^[\w@.-]+$` which is shorter :)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I realized that i need to accept : and \ and also one . only for the file extension. Do you have any suggestion on what regex to use? thanks

Comment: How many dots [?](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767) If several then `[\w@.:\\\\-]+$` would do the job.

Comment: How do you know what operating system the client is running on? How do you know what file system the file name comes from? You can't do what you want, I'm afraid. At least, not without almost assuredly locking out some users, now or in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually did the trick:
`^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9 ._:\\]*[\.]?[A-Za-z0-9]+$`

this accepts the path with only 1 `.`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following provide a decent match for a Windows filename/directory structure:

```
^[A-Z]:(\\[^\\/:*?"<>|]+)+.\w+$
```

(Note that blacklist came from Windows Explorer after trying to enter in a bad character.)

Example matches:

```
$ grep -P '^[A-Z]:(\\[^\\/:*?"<>|]+)+.\w+$' file_list.txt 
C:\Sample File5.txt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows\file.exe
C:\Program Files\Jon's folder\file.pdf
C:\my-file.txt
C:\5@^&[]{}!#i.txt.exe
```

If you want to change that to a whitelist, modify accordingly:

```
$ grep -P '^[A-Z]:(\\[\w\s@-]+)+.\w+$' file_list.txt 
C:\Sample File5.txt
C:\my-file.txt
```